# Django template - Iterating through data with conditional effect related to category

Tags: python, html, django, loops, templates

I have data source with structure that looks like this:

```
[{
    category: 'A',
    name: 'item 1',
    count: 11
 },
{
    category: 'A',
    name: 'item 2',
    count: 22
 },
 {
    category: 'A',
    name: 'item 3',
    count: 33
 },
{
    category: 'B',
    name: 'item 5',
    count: 44
 }, 
 etc...
]
```

Lets call this data source a 'response'

So, for now in django template I am able to do

```
<table><tbody>
{% for item in response %}
    <tr><td>{{item.name}}</td><td> {{result.count}}</td><tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody></table>
```

The effect of this is

```
Item 1 11
Item 2 22
Item 3 33
Item 5 44
...
```

But I am willing to achieve this:

```
Category A  
Item 1  11
Item 2  22
Item 3  33
Category B  
Item 5  44
Item 6  55
Category C  
Item 4  66
```

So it could have effect like this:

```
<tr><th>Category A</th></tr>
<tr><td>Item 1</td><td>11</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 2</td><td>22</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 3</td><td>33</td></tr>
<tr><th>Category B</th></tr>
<tr><td>Item 5</td><td>44</td></tr>
...
```

In PHP I have always done it using temporary variable where I was holding previous category name and compared it each time when new element of data source was used. Is it possible to do similar thing in Django Template? If no is there any other, simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag in this case.

```
<table><tbody>
{% for item in response %}
    {% ifchanged item.category %}Category {{ item.category }}{% endifchanged %}
    <tr><td>{{item.name}}</td><td> {{result.count}}</td><tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody></table>
```

The [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)) tag could be another option.

Note that `ifchanged` and `regroup` will only work if the list is already sorted by category. If not, you might need the [`dictsort`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort) filter

In general, you can't assign variables in the Django template language. The recommended approach would be to transform your data in your view (or a template tag) to a different format, e.g.

```
[
    ['Category A', [<items>],
    ['Category B', [<items>],
    ...
]
```

It would then be simple to iterate through the new data structure in the template.

Comment: will it work correctly if the order of elements in the data is changed?

Comment: No. This won't work if the list is not sorted by category - but neither will the OP's approach of storing the previous value in a variable and comparing. There is a [`dictsort`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsort) filter, but as I said before, I recommend sorting and formatting the data in the view rather than the template.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should transform your data before showing it.

You could have a function like this on the backend:

```
def _to_dict(name, count):
    return {'name': name, 'count': count}


def _data_to_table(data):
    table = []

    previous_category = None
    for item in data:
        item_category = item['category']
        if item_category != previous_category:
            table.append(_to_dict('Category {}'.format(item_category), ''))

        previous_category = item_category
        table.append(_to_dict(item['name'],item['count']))
    return table
```

That would transform your data into something like this

```
[{'count': '', 'name': 'Category A'},
 {'count': 11, 'name': 'item 1'},
 {'count': 22, 'name': 'item 2'},
 {'count': 33, 'name': 'item 3'},
 {'count': '', 'name': 'Category B'},
 {'count': 44, 'name': 'item 5'}]
```

and you could show the way you like better on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but i'm pretty sure this will work, and you don't have to change your data or anything.

```
<tr><th>Category A</th></tr>
<table><tbody>
{% for item in response %}
{% if item.category == 'A' %}
<tr><td>{{item.name}}</td><td> {{result.count}}</td><tr>
{% enfif %}
{% endfor %}
</tbody></table>

<tr><th>Category B</th></tr>
<table><tbody>
{% for item in response %}
{% if item.category == 'B' %}
<tr><td>{{item.name}}</td><td> {{result.count}}</td><tr>
{% enfif %}
{% endfor %}
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: This will get very repetitive if there are more than two categories.

Comment: Yeah, now that i saw your answer i agree with you. I didn't know about the ifchanged. Just one doubt: Isn't the Category tag be shown for each iteration with ifchanged?

Comment: With `{% ifchanged item.category %}Category {{ item.category }}{% endifchanged %}`, It will only display `Category X` if the category is different from last time. That seems to be what the OP wanted.

Comment: Nice! Good to know. Thanks @Alasdair! And i agree, this is exactly what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is first create a dictionary and append all the name and count pair that have same category value. Then you can make a list of key value pair of the that dict and iterate over it. Here is a code for same

```
d={}
for item in response:
    if item['category'] in d:
        d[item['category']].append([item['name'],item['count']])
    else:
        d[item['category']] = [[item['name'],item['count']]]

new_list=[] 
for key,value in d.items():
    new_list.append([key,value])
print(new_list)
```

This is how you template should look like.

```
{% for item in new_list %}
    Category {{ item.0 }}
    {% for i in item.1 %}
        <tr><td>{{i.0}}</td><td> {{i.1}}</td><tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```